# Java AccessControlException: keeping getting File IO error when trying to write log file

Tags: java, linux

I keep getting an Java IO exception when the application is trying to initialize the log.  Here is the stack trace.   `/var/lib/tomcat6/logs` has permission for anyone to read and write to it.

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission /var/lib/tomcat6/logs/socksserver.log write)
    java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
    java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    java.lang.SecurityManager.checkWrite(SecurityManager.java:962)
    java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
    java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:102)
    common.log.ThreadFileWriter.init(ThreadFileWriter.java:50)
    common.log.LogConfiguration.initLog(LogConfiguration.java:50)
    socksviahttp.server.ServletSocks.logInit(ServletSocks.java:113)
    socksviahttp.server.ServletSocks.init(ServletSocks.java:59)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:244)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:115)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception stack trace indicates it's not a file permission error, but rather you're running Tomcat under a security manager, for which you have not set up the permission to allow it to write to that path.

`policytool` is a neat program to help you create policy files that you can configure the security manager with.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I have the exact same problem as you or that I've even fully solved my own, however, here's a shot at helping out. In short I think it might have to do with the Java Security Manager and the configuration of your $CATALINA_BASE path.

I've been getting the following error messages from my Tomcat6 Solr 1.3 install on a daily basis:

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission /var/lib/tomcat6/logs read)
       at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:342)
       at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:553)
       at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
       at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
       at java.io.File.exists(File.java:748)
       at java.io.File.mkdirs(File.java:1195)

.......

The file permissions were set correctly for the log directory and the logs were created after the message was thrown the first time. But the error would recur the next day with the creation of a newly rotated log file.

After a bit of digging I learned that the error was being thrown by the Java Security Manager and don't have anything to do with OS file permissions. As it turned out the JSM logging settings were being driven off of the $CATALINA_BASE path which was not correctly configured in my installation. $CATALINA_BASE should point to the location of the dynamically created files for tomcat, however, when not configured it defaults to the $CATALINA_HOME dir which is where the tomcat binaries live. As a result I'm not sure that JSM had the correct permissions to manipulate files in the log directory.

I've added CATALINA_BASE = "/var/lib/tomcat6" to my catalina.sh file and believe that I've resolved the problem.

Hopefully this is correct/helpful information!